# Nameserver Change Not Working

Tags: ip, vps, hostname, nameservers, reverse-dns

HELP!

I'm new to the whole VPS world! I changed from a shared server to a VPS! I think I set up my server properly! Along with migrating previous content! However, I'm not sure I created my Hostname and Nameserver right. This is because, I registered my Nameserver with my domain registrar and updated my Nameserver through them! It does look like it got propagated properly! However, now my websites aren't loading and I get the following message:
[Safari can't open the page ... because Safari can't find the server ...][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4wV9.png

and when I go to a tool like [Pingdom DNS Check Tool](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=donaldlouch.ca&timestamp=1486582816&view=2) I get the following error messages:

- Nameserver ns2.donaldlouch.ca is listed for zone donaldlouch.ca without address information.
- (3) Reverse for 191.101.227.106 points to an unknown host name (601.722.191.in-addr.arpa).
- Reverse for 191.101.238.211 points to an unknown host name (112.832.101.191.in-addr.arpa)
- Delivery over IPv4 to admin@donaldlouch.ca could not be done.
- and: Failed to deliver email for SOA RNAME of donaldlouch.ca (admin.donaldlouch.ca) using admin@donaldlouch.ca.

I have tried:

- to Google solutions
- change Nameserver address
- change Hostname
- change rDNS
- restart my VPS

and nothing seems to be working. I, thinking it may have something to do with the rDNS? Does this look like it would be a proper rDNS: 
`112.832.101.191.in-addr.arpa` for an IP of `191.101.238.211`?

My Hostname is:
`vps.donaldlouch.ca`

and my Nameservers should be pointed at

- `ns1.donaldlouch.ca - 191.101.227.106`
- `ns2.donaldlouch.ca - 191.101.238.211`

I'm running CentOS 7 and cPanel/WHM, for my DNS I'm using BIND!

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
I got it to work!!! I just need to wait for the full global propagation to go through!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!!! I just need to wait for the full global propagation to go through!